# Why does Typescript ignore an error while I import type from other npm package?

Tags: typescript

I have a library with a type. This type is exported from the library and imported into my project.

```js
export type TDrawingItem = {
    id: number;
    type: TDrawingType;
    settings: TDrawingSettings;
};
```

tsconfig.json of my library:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@types": ["./src/types/types.ts"],
      "@utils": ["./src/utils.ts"],
      "@constants": ["./src/constants.ts"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And package.json part:

```json
  "source": "./src/index.ts",
  "main": "./dist/bundle/index.min.js",
  "browser": "./dist/umd/index.min.js",
  "module": "./dist/modules/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/modules/index.d.ts",
```

I build it with rollup and everything is okay. But when I try to use exported type in my code, I don't get any errors:

```js
import type { TDrawingItem } from 'my-package';
// ...
const item: TDrawingItem = {}; // it must throw error
```

Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to share a git repo with the same issue? It is difficult to troubleshoot this issue as it pertains to your environment. It could be an issue with your IDE, something that we do not have access to on SO and can not be solved by simply reading your config.

Comment: When you hover over `TDrawingItem` in the last snippet of code you posted, what does your editor report the type as?

Comment: I've found an answer. The problem is with aliases. When I'm re-exporting types from alias (which is described in tsconfig of the library) types aren't being validated